# How to add many spaces after the text in TextView

Tags: android, string, user-interface, whitespace, textview

I want to add Many spaces to the right of my text for printing blank space in the TextView
For example:

```
String text="text";
TextView=textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(text+"      ");
```

Comment: `TextView=textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);` should be `TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);`

Comment: use padding or margin instead of spaces

Comment: why would you need to add those extra spaces?

Comment: And what is wrong with your current approach?  Why not just give the TextView an appropriate width?

Comment: When the text Fill the textView, this cannot add more spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By transforming Text as Html,you can solve that problem 
this is one way to solve that : 
 message.setText(Html.fromHtml((myString + "     &#160"));

Answer (score 2):

You used this in TextView:

```
   <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A&#160;B&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;C"/>
```

Happy Coding ;)

Comment: When the text Fill the textView, this cannot add more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This'll be dirty, maybe you should consider constraining your `textView` to desired size & position in layout instead.

Anyway, this'll work as long as you know how many spaces you need.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(YOUR_TEXT);

for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SPACES_YOU_WANT; i++ ){
  builder.append(" ");
}
```

If you don't know how many spaces you need then calculate distance from text ending to desired size.

Or again you can simply constraint your `textView` in layout and skip all the pain.

Comment: When the text Fill the textView, this cannot add more spaces.

Comment: Of course there are more conditions to handle compared to setting view properties in XML.

Comment: How can I resolve this? Can you please give an entire solution?

Comment: I'd like to, but can you be more specific with how do you want this textView to look like ?

Comment: I fund solution by using This code : 
message.setText(Html.fromHtml((myString + "     &#160"));